# app.java:14: error: illegal start of expression how to fix it?(i just started learning java...)

Tags: java

```
app.java:14: error: illegal start of expression
.
^
app.java:16: error: 'else' without 'if'
else {
^

2 errors
```

the whole code is:

```
class app {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 10;

        if (number > 0) {
            System.out.println("The number is positive.");
        }
        else if(number < 0) {
            System.out.println("The number is not positive.");
        }
        else if (number > 0) {
            System.out.println("The number is positive.");
        }
        .
        .
        else {
             System.out.println("Congrats you just solved the math in here!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `.
.` to do?

Comment: i dont know im a noob + copied it from a tutorial of someone else...

Comment: does someone know why i doesn't get the "Congrats..." when i change the int number to a false one like -5 ?

Comment: because your entered number is positive or negative or zero, and one of your 3 `if-statement` become true. so your last `else` won't run...

Comment: @MortezaAsadi how can i run the last else? because no matter what(0,true,false) it doesn't run...

Comment: why when i run a false is not print "The number is not positive." twice...?

Answer (score 0):

Remove (.) at line 14 and 15 try this.

```
if(true){
        
}
else if(true){
        
}
else if(true){
        
}
else{
        
}
```